# Dynamic DisplayName in Junit 5

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

Is there anyway we can achieve dynamic DisplayName in Junit 5 ( eg : replace with system properties )

```
@DisplayName("The test cases is running agains {os.name}")
public void testOSVersion(){
     .....
}
```

We want to do this to make test cases more descriptive.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible by default.

#### `TestReporter`

With the *current* Jupiter versions you may always use the `TestReporter` to emit extra data to the reports:

```
@Test
void testOSVersion(TestReporter testReporter) {
    testReporter.publishEntry("os.name", System.getProperty("os.name"));
}
```

For details see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dependency-injection

#### `DisplayNameGenerator`

The *upcoming* version 5.4.0 of Jupiter, available as a SNAPSHOT already, supports an annotation called `@DisplayNameGeneration` that points to a custom `DisplayNameGenerator` implementation. Here you may generate a display name for a test method dynamically, using it's name, attached annotations, etc...

For details, see
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#display-name-generators

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles on this question, as I did, looking to customize the `DisplayName`s for `ParameterizedTest`s, there **ARE** a few options available: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-display-names. The example from the docs is:

```
@DisplayName("Display name of container")
@ParameterizedTest(name = "{index} ==> the rank of ''{0}'' is {1}")
@CsvSource({ "apple, 1", "banana, 2", "'lemon, lime', 3" })
void testWithCustomDisplayNames(String fruit, int rank) {
   ...
}
```

Results in the following output:

```
Display name of container ✔
├─ 1 ==> the rank of 'apple' is 1 ✔
├─ 2 ==> the rank of 'banana' is 2 ✔
└─ 3 ==> the rank of 'lemon, lime' is 3 ✔
```